# RenderAction and RedirectToAction on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have a master page called layout.cshtml and a page called testpage.cshtml.

On this page i have a RenderAction that returns a PartialView.

Is it possible to return a RedirectToAction inside the Action that returns a PartialView?

Im getting a "child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions" exception and i would like to know if its caused by this reason.

Looks logical that you should not redirect from a "UserControl" in MVC right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No thats not possible. You can't redirect a part of the page.

What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: The thing is that im working with a controllers arquitecture really poor and all url request are passing by the same action with a parameter viewname, this forces to do this kind of redirections in every "user control action" instead on "page actions" (where should be if needed). Thanks for the clear response, was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation behind the error you get is that Ajax calls can not perform redirect.
Try something else.